# Python & Flask, send and receive data from server

Tags: python, flask, get

I am trying to do a practice, which consists of sending some data from an html form, receive it, execute a function and return it to the html.

From the index.html file, I have declared a form with the `<form>` label.
With the action attribute, I pass to the URL **/products/mouse** the name of a product, which is defined in a dictionary inside a file with the name products.py.

This value is collected by the `index()` function, calls the `getProduct()` function and passes it the variable `product_nombre` which contains the value mouse sent from index.html.

`getProduct`, goes through the products dictionary looking for a product that matches the name of the product sent by html, in this case, mouse.

The question is that in the index.html, it indicates to me:

> Producto no encontrado - *Product not found when the product exists*

Why does this happen?

this is the content of my main **app.py** file:

```py
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, render_template, redirect, url_for
from products import products

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    product_nombre = request.args.get('product_nombre', 'punto control')
    data = getProduct(product_nombre)
    return render_template('index.html', data=data)

@app.route('/products/<string:product_nombre>', methods=['GET'])
def getProduct(product_nombre):
    for product in products:
        if product['nombre'] == product_nombre:
            return product
    return "Producto no encontrado"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

this is the contents of my **index.html** file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/products/mouse" method="get">
        <h2 id=>Hola mundo</h2>
        <h4> {{ data }}</h4>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

this is the content of the file **products.py**

```py
products = [ 
    {"nombre": "laptop",
    "precio": 800,
    "cantidad": 4},
    {"nombre": "mouse",
    "precio": 40,
    "cantidad": 10},
    {"nombre": "monitor",
    "precio": 250,
    "cantidad": 3}
    ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> in the index.html, it indicates to me:
>
> > Producto no encontrado

I take this to mean that it happens in `@app.route('/')`, right? Well, then what's the flow there?

> ```
> product_nombre = request.args.get('product_nombre', 'punto control')
> ```

This gets a *request argument*, i.e. URL query parameters. If you just visit `localhost:5000/` (or whatever), then there are no arguments. So `product_nombre` will get the default value of `'punto control'`. Well, then `getProduct(product_nombre)` of course doesn't match anything, because there's no product "punto control", so you get the default `return "Producto no encontrado"`.

Comment: Thanks so much for trying to help me @deceze.
I want that when I wake up the server, the index.html file is executed. Once executed, from the form I call the function **getProduct()** with the syntax: 
<form action="/products/mouse" method="get">

My goal is to display the result of **getProduct** in **index.html**.

I can't manage to capture the mouse value from **index.html** and pass it to the **getProduct()** function correctly. That is my problem.

Thanks again

Comment: That's just not really how it works. Why is `/products/<string:product_nombre>` a separate route if you're just calling it within `def index`? Are you trying to make an AJAX request?

Comment: This is because it is a simplified version of my original code.
My objective is to make a REST API, and implement PUT, GET, etc, queries.

All the functions associated with these query are rendered from **app.route('/products/<string:product_name>')** since product_name is the variable I use to query the database and return a JSON.

To see where I was making the mistake, I have been simplifying and reducing my code to the minimum expression and this is the simplest example of my problem.

Comment: Yeah, so, if you do go to `/products/mouse` in your browser, then yes, you'll get your JSON. But in `/` (index), you're rendering the HTML template, but you're not passing "mouse" anywhere. Try opening `/?product_nombre=mouse`…?!

Comment: Yes, yes, if I access **products/mouse** in my browser, I get the result I am looking for.
But I want that same result in the root (/).
How do I send the result of **http://127.0.0.1:5000/products/mouse** to the root, to **index.html**?

Comment: You do not "send" something from one URL to another! HTTP is a request-response system. You send one request, you get one response. The response you get solely depends on the request. A different request is a completely separate request which will get a completely separate response. Again, I don't know why you have two separate routes to begin with.